# Bower install dependency to a specific subdirectory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

How do I install a dependency into a specific subdirectory using Bower? I'm working on an application built on AngularJS that requires localization. One of the libraries I'm using is looking for localization files in angular/angular_i18n. However, I'm developing with Angular 1.2 rc3 and the localization files are not part of the package so I have to install them separately.

How can I bower install angular-i18n into components/angular/angular-i18n/?

Help would be totally appreciated.

Comment: You can also just provide a .bowerrc file as mentioned in [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671533/how-do-i-install-bower-dependencies-in-a-specific-directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Bower uses a single location to store packages. However you can use tools like  [one of these grunt tasks](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/bower) to copy it over in the build-step.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This seems like just what I need

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to use this fork:  https://github.com/hyperweb2/upt

that also implements subdirectory installation feature