# How do I install bower dependencies in a specific directory?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I'm building a yeoman generator for simple websites.
I want to include a popular JavaScript library in my scaffold.

It's easy enough with `bower install <mylib>`. Bower then installs the library in the directory `bower_components`.

How can configure bower to install that particular library in a particular directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bower install dependency to a specific subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552672/bower-install-dependency-to-a-specific-subdirectory)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a file called `.bowerrc` in the same directory as your `bower.json` with the contents:

```
{
  "directory": "bower"
}
```

Bower will then install all dependencies in the directory "bower" or whatever directory you specify.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to have a default directory, but then send a single dependency to another directory? Perhaps: "dependencies": { "special": { source: "http...git", directory: "./special-tools" } }